# Constraint Animation issue in CollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

unfortunately, I continue to have problems with the constraints ... I'm definitely my problem but I really can not understand them ...

I've created a UICollectionView with custom cells.

Inside the cells I inserted an UIView with all its constraints.

Uiview height constraint is set to ZERO by default and changes based on data collected by the collectionView from a NSMutableArray

In the cellForItemAtIndexPath method increase or decrease the uiview height that is in the custom cell ...

Everything works well, the data is collected to perfection but I do not understand why the uiview height animation continues every time I scroll the collectionView ..

I would like the height of the view to be animated when the collectionView is shown but not when I scroll back or forward ... I created a video to show you this

https://streamable.com/d32fy

I do not understand where I'm wrong, are days that I'm stuck for some issues that I can not understand with the constraints and their animations ...

this is the code I'm using

**Main View Controller**

```
-(void)setupCollectionView {

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 2;
    flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0;
    flowLayout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;

    _chartCollection = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero collectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
    [_chartCollection registerClass:[KPHomeChartCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:kChartCellIdentifier];
    _chartCollection.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    _chartCollection.delegate = self;
    _chartCollection.dataSource = self;
    _chartCollection.pagingEnabled = YES;
    _chartCollection.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    _chartCollection.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self addSubview:_chartCollection];

    self.topChartCollectionAnchor = [self.chartCollection.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.customSwitch.bottomAnchor constant:20];
    self.topChartCollectionAnchor.active = YES;
    [self.chartCollection.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.leftAnchor constant:30].active = YES;
    [self.chartCollection.rightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.rightAnchor].active = YES;
    [self.chartCollection.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.bottomAnchor constant:-35].active = YES;

    [self buildYAxis];
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    KPHomeChartCell *chartCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kChartCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSInteger n = [[self returnXAxis][indexPath.item] integerValue];
    UILabel *yLabelValue = (UILabel *)[self viewWithTag:n];

    chartCell.leftBarHeightConstraint.constant = [self offsetBarFromChart:collectionView] - yLabelValue.center.y;

    chartCell.rightBarHeightConstraint.constant = [self offsetBarFromChart:collectionView] - yLabelValue.center.y +30;

    return chartCell;
}
```

**Custom CollectionViewCell**

```
-(void)animateHeightOfBarWithConstant {
  // Crea la linea a tratti per ogni barra
    CAShapeLayer *dashedLine = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    CGMutablePathRef thePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(thePath, nil, 0, 0);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(thePath, nil, 0, self.contentView.frame.size.height);

    dashedLine.path = thePath;
    CGPathRelease(thePath);
    dashedLine.lineDashPattern = @[@4];
    dashedLine.strokeColor =  [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#FFFFFF" setAlpha:.1].CGColor;
    [self.contentView.layer addSublayer:dashedLine];


    // BUILD BAR UIVIEW
    _bar = [[UIView alloc] init];
    _bar.layer.cornerRadius = 4;
    _bar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    CGFloat barWidth = 15;
    [self.contentView addSubview:_bar];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                dashedLine.frame = CGRectMake(_bar.center.x, 0, self.contentView.frame.size.width , 15);
            });


    [self.bar.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.contentView.bottomAnchor].active = YES;
    [self.bar.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:barWidth].active = YES;
    [self.bar.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.contentView.centerXAnchor constant:-13.5].active = YES;

     self.leftBarHeightConstraint = [self.bar.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:0];
     self.leftBarHeightConstraint.active = YES;

     [UIView animateWithDuration:.9 animations:^{
         [self.contentView layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```

Comment: I don't think the problem is related to constraints here. In my opinion the issue is occurring because you are reusing the cells by using `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code

Main View Controller

```
@interface MainViewController () <UITableViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger lastCellDisplayedIndex;

@end

@implementation MainViewController

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  _lastCellDisplayedIndex = indexPath.row;
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  KPHomeChartCell *chartCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kChartCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

  NSInteger n = [[self returnXAxis][indexPath.item] integerValue];
  UILabel *yLabelValue = (UILabel *)[self viewWithTag:n];

  chartCell.leftBarHeightConstraint.constant = [self offsetBarFromChart:collectionView] - yLabelValue.center.y;

  chartCell.rightBarHeightConstraint.constant = [self offsetBarFromChart:collectionView] - yLabelValue.center.y +30;

  if (_lastCellDisplayedIndex >= indexPath) {
    [chartCell updateHeightOfBarAnimated:NO];
  } else {
    [chartCell updateHeightOfBarAnimated:YES];
  }

  return chartCell;
}

@end
```

**Custom CollectionViewCell**

```
-(void)updateHeightOfBarAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
  // Crea la linea a tratti per ogni barra
  CAShapeLayer *dashedLine = [CAShapeLayer layer];
  CGMutablePathRef thePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
  CGPathMoveToPoint(thePath, nil, 0, 0);
  CGPathAddLineToPoint(thePath, nil, 0, self.contentView.frame.size.height);

  dashedLine.path = thePath;
  CGPathRelease(thePath);
  dashedLine.lineDashPattern = @[@4];
  dashedLine.strokeColor =  [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#FFFFFF" setAlpha:.1].CGColor;
  [self.contentView.layer addSublayer:dashedLine];


  // BUILD BAR UIVIEW
  _bar = [[UIView alloc] init];
  _bar.layer.cornerRadius = 4;
  _bar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
  CGFloat barWidth = 15;
  [self.contentView addSubview:_bar];

  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    dashedLine.frame = CGRectMake(_bar.center.x, 0, self.contentView.frame.size.width , 15);
  });


  [self.bar.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.contentView.bottomAnchor].active = YES;
  [self.bar.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:barWidth].active = YES;
  [self.bar.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.contentView.centerXAnchor constant:-13.5].active = YES;

  self.leftBarHeightConstraint = [self.bar.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:0];
  self.leftBarHeightConstraint.active = YES;

  if (animated) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.9 animations:^{
      [self.contentView layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
  } else {
    [self.contentView layoutIfNeeded];
  }
}

- (void)prepareForReuse {
    if (_bar) {
      [_bar removeFromSuperview];
      _bar = nil;
    }
  }
```

Use `updateHeightOfBarAnimated` only in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`

Comment: Your cell will be fine after calling `updateHeightOfBarAnimated:`again at `cellForItemAtIndexPath`

Comment: they have implemented as you suggested me but you do not get any results .. maybe i'm wrong about something ... do you have two minutes so I'll show you my chat code in chat? maybe it's simpler

Comment: Me too ). Do you have Skype or anything else?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157829/discussion-between-kain-and-trungduc).

Answer (score 1):

If animation is wanted only for 1. appearance do something like this:

1. In viewDidAppear take and save current time in seconds NSTimeInterval startTime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
2. In cellForIndexPath if time of initial animation passed -> ([NSDate date] timeintervalSinceReferenceData] - startTime) > animationTime set size of the view as in final state of animation (so no animation will happen)
3. function animateHeightOfBarWithConstant() should probably have a parametrer (BOOL)animated. If it is set to YES, do the animation(time of animation is non-zero),  if you send NO, time of animation is 0 or use [UIView performWithoutAnimation:]

Use -prepareForReuse() method on cell. Cells are reused and you need to set right start condition or set all atributes in cellForIndexPath method.